# Convolution in Schwarz Space

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, schwartz-space

Suppose $f,g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Schwarz space on $\mathbb{R}$. Then we need to show that
$$ x (f *g) = (xf)*g  \;\;\;\; \mbox{      a.e. }$$ So, can anyone help me in proving this?

P.S. : Convolution of 2 functions is defined as $$ (f*g )(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-y) g(y) \; dy $$

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I tried but couldn't made any progress

Comment: Because it is obviously not true

Comment: @reuns so can you please provide any counterexample

Comment: $f=g=e^{-x^2}$ then $(x^2 f)\ast g$ doesn't vanish at $0$

Comment: @reuns Oh yes, you're correct, but this doesn't holds for one point. So, can we have equality almost everywhere (a.e.) ?